# How to build a CodeWarrior v6.3 Project in command line?

Tags: command-line, build, codewarrior

Refer to [this](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/IDE_5.6_Automation_Guide.pdf) documentation, I try to build an old Code Warrior V6.3 Project (.mcp) via command line.

```
PS C:\Program Files (x86)\Freescale\CodeWarrior for Microcontrollers V6.3\bin> .\cmdide /q /f n /b C:\Users\ps\Desktop\LadeHeiz_WORKON\LadeHeiz.mcp

Freescale CodeWarrior IDE. Hit /? for help

No Error. (Code 0)
```

So console output says **No Error** but the UI-IDE is opening and gives me this error message:

[image: Error]

A look to the bin folder of my project tells me, that the generated .s19 is not updated, so the build process didn't run.

**Question:** Has anyone experiences with CW6.3 command line tool and can give me some hints how to build the old project? The GUI based IDE is not an option, because we have to automatically build the project in an CI-System.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is very simple. The option `/q` (quit) must not be called without calling `/c` (close) before.

```
PS C:\Program Files (x86)\Freescale\CodeWarrior for Microcontrollers V6.3\bin> .\cmdide /r /b C:\Users\ps\Desktop\LadeHeiz_WORKON\LadeHeiz.mcp /c /q

Freescale CodeWarrior IDE. Hit /? for help

No Error. (Code 0)
```

Now there is the following workflow

1. Delete old build files
2. Build new files (refer to the specific path)
3. Close project
4. Quit CodeWarrior